# IPhone Get Parent View of UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitextfield

I have a UITextField control and I just want to get the parent view that it is contained in. I was hoping it would be something like [MyTextField ParentView] or MyTextField.view but no go.

Any ideas?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use `myTextField.superview`. It's documented in [Apple's class reference for the UIView class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html), which UITextField inherits from.

Answer (score 9):

It's `myTextField.superview`.